# ArcGIS Server: Limit creation of cache tiles to certain areas by providing a feature class

Tags: arcgis-server, tiles, map-service, cache

I am publishing a map service to ArcGIS Server 10.0. I cannot succeed to **limit the creation of tiles to certain areas only**, instead of creating them for the entire map. According to [this help document ("Map caching based on feature boundaries
")](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Map_caching_based_on_feature_boundaries/00930000006z000000/), as far as I understand, this should be possible.

In my map document I have an aerial photo of an area containing some villages. I have a shape file polygon feature class with rectangular polygons containing the villages. I want to provide this feature class to limit the creation of tiles only to the portions of the aerial photo within these bounding rectangles. I am not interested in the rural areas in between the villages. It would be a waste of computing time and disk space to have tiles created outside the rectangles.

I followed the steps in the above mentioned help document closely, providing my shape file here:
*Tool "Manage Map Server Cache Tiles" -> Update specific areas using a feature class ->
Update Extents Feature Class (optional) -> MyBoundingBoxes.shp*

Unfortunately my feature class is completely ignored. When I examin the resulting PNG tiles, I notice that tiles were created for the **entire** map, also for the rural areas in between.

Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to populate the cache in a discontinuous collection of extents, you need to re-execute the population command with singleton polygons in each extent.  If you use a multi-row polygon shapefile, it will calculate the envelope of the entire shapefile and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I only get the extent of the polygon by using feature class in a file geodatabase. Whenever  I used a shapefile I got the entire map.

Comment: Could you provide additional resources to make your answer more thorough?